# What is the difference between string::at and string::operator[]?

Tags: c++, string

I was taught `string::at` in school, but by exploring the string library I saw `string::operator[]`, which I was never shown before.

I'm now using `operator[]` and haven't used `at` since, but what is the difference?
Here is some sample code:

```
std::string foo = "my redundant string has some text";
std::cout << foo[5];
std::cout << foo.at(5);
```

They are essentially the same in terms of output, but are there some subtle differences I'm not aware of?

Comment: Did you try a reference for each? There is a difference, which should be pretty easy to spot when comparing references.

Comment: Wait, you decided to switch from `.at()` to `operator[]` *before* looking into a book or online reference ?

Comment: well, I read operator[] was faster, but didn't know why...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes, there is one major difference: using [`.at()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/at) does a range check on index passed and throws an exception if it's over the end of the string while [`operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at) just brings **undefined behavior** in that situation.

Answer (score 20):

[`at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/at) **does bounds checking**, exception of type `std::out_of_range` will be thrown on invalid access.

[`operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at) **does NOT check bounds** and thus can be dangerous if you try to access beyond the bounds of the string. It is a little faster than `at` though.

Answer (score 8):

**std::string::at**

Returns a reference to the character at specified location pos. Bounds checking is performed, exception of type std::out_of_range will be thrown on invalid access.

**string::operator[]**

Returns a reference to the character at specified location pos. No bounds checking is performed. It's undefefined behavior to access out-of-boundary  with `operator[]`.

`string::operator[]` should be silghtly faster than `std::string::at`

see the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)