# Difference between std::string [] operator and at()

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm revisiting C++ after a few years of C#, Javascript, web development etc.

There is a thread where it is explained that the major difference between these is that the at() method does bounds checking and throws an exception if the index provided is out of bounds.

[What is the difference between string::at and string::operator[]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14699060/what-is-the-difference-between-stringat-and-stringoperator)

However, that does not seem to justify the following behavior I am experiencing, perhaps someone could help me out?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void remodel(string & str){
    string * ps = new string(str);

    ps->at(0) = 'n';
    cout<<*ps<<endl;
    delete ps;
}

int main(){
    string str = "Hello world";
    remodel(str);
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

### Output

```
nello world
```

In the above code, I use the at() method to change the first character of the string, and am successfully able to do so. Printing the string confirms this.

Something different happens when using the [] operator:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void remodel(string & str){
    string * ps = new string(str);
    ps[0] = 'n';
    cout<<*ps<<endl;
    delete ps;
}

int main(){
    string str = "Hello world";

    remodel(str);

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

### Output

```
n
```

In the above code, using the [] operator on the index 0 replaces the entire string with the letter 'n'. This is confirmed in the debugger where I can see a complete reassignment of values from "Hello world" to "n"

Just to elaborate, if I place a breakpoint so the program stops just before executing ps[0] = 'n', then upon [inspecting the variable ps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaHbd.png), it seemingly stores an address that is used to reach the string "Hello world". After executing this line, however, the same address can only be used to reach the string/character "n".

My hypothesis was that using the [] operator results in a null character being placed just after specified index..but I have been unable to confirm this.

for example, in the above code using ps[0] I tried to print ps[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaHbd.png), ps[2] just to see what would come.

What I got in output either a neverending (empty) output of what seemed like spaces, or a bunch of gibberish. It seems for my null character hypothesis for not to be the case. For good measure, I also tried to manually place a null character at some position like ps[10] but got a segmentation fault..the memory previously allocated to my string had gone out of bounds!

So, it appears I need a good revision on this topic, can someone explain whats going on? Please feel free to let me know if something in this question is vague or badly expressed, I'll do my best to fix it.

Comment: Don't use `string*`. Just use `string` directly. You weren't calling `string::operator[]`, but the built in `[]` operator for pointers

Comment: With `at` ["Bounds checking is performed, exception of type std::out_of_range will be thrown on invalid access."](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/at)

Comment: "_In the above code, using the [] operator on the index 0 replaces the entire string with the letter 'n'_" It's because `ps[0]` doesn't do what you think it does. It **doesn't** even invoke the `operator[]` of `std::string`. In this case, `ps[0] = 'n'` is equivalent to `*ps = 'n'`.

Comment: You need to deference the pointer before you can invoke the operator or use really goofy looking syntax. eg: `(*ps)[0] = 'n';` But prefer to not use the pointer or raw dynamic allocation.

Comment: For any array ***or pointer*** `p` and index `i`, the expression `p[i]` is equal to `*(p + i)`. With `ps[0]` you're dereferencing the pointer `ps` to get the first element in the "array" it points to. It is equal to `*ps = 'n'`.

Comment: `ps->operator[](0) = 'n';` is another way, if you are so inclined.

Comment: @Mat Or just `(*ps)[0] = 'n';`

Comment: Recommended reading: [Why should C++ programmers minimize use of 'new'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new)

Comment: Thank you all! In all honesty, I guess I was not differentiating between the string [] operator and the pointer [] operator..in the sense that I was taking both to be the same thing. My key takeaway here is that they are quite distinct. In which case, in the particular example (*ps)[0] = 'n' would do what I actually was trying to do. All the responses have been enlightening.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between string::at and string::operator\[\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14699060/what-is-the-difference-between-stringat-and-stringoperator)

Comment: @phuclv No.  This question is about the difference between string::at and the builtin operator[].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second program is malformed.  It's not using `std::string::operator[]` at all.

```
string * ps = new string(str);
ps[0] = 'n';
```

Not only does `std::string` support the `[]` operator, **every pointer to a type** also supports the `[]` operator.  It's how C style arrays work, and it's what you're doing in the code above.

`ps`  isn't a `string`.  It's a pointer.  And `ps[0]` is the one string, not unlike `*ps`.

You probably wanted [this](https://www.ideone.com/sSMOLQ) instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void remodel(string & str){
    string * ps = new string(str);
    (*ps)[0] = 'n';
    // or: ps->operator[](0) = 'n';
    cout<<*ps<<endl;
    delete ps;
}

int main(){
    string str = "Hello world";

    remodel(str);

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Or, more idiomatically, use [this](https://www.ideone.com/80oFtA) instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void remodel(string & str){
    string ps = str;
    ps[0] = 'n';
    cout<<ps<<endl;
}

int main(){
    string str = "Hello world";

    remodel(str);

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why not pass `str` by value and remove the `ps`?

Comment: well depends if OP wanted to modify `str` or not, you dont

Comment: There are certainly a lot of refinements that could be made to the code beyond "Why isn't this doing what I expect?" ... I started sliding down that slope myself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
tbh, I think this question itself culminated from me going off on a tangent while following a book section on the auto_ptr. To open the problem, the book put forward the remodel function (but with only the first line similar to mine), and I kind of started sliding down from there...